# Definition of Short Authentication String

Tags: public-key, authentication

I am studying for my cryptography final and I passed by the following term: short authentication string. Please, can anyone explain it to me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Short Authentication String (SAS) is used in various protocols, but in short, SAS is produced to transfer a long authentication tag into a smaller so that the two users can verbally verify. For example;

In [Diffie-Hellman key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), there is always a risk of [Man-in-the-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack. To ensure that there is no attacker in the first session, that there are no shared secrets yet, a SAS can be used. After verbal communication, if the values don't match then Man-in-the-Middle attack is detected.

Some Protocols that uses SAS;

- [ZRTP: Media Path Key Agreement for Unicast Secure RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6189#section-4.4.1.1)
- [Short Authentication Strings for TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-miers-tls-sas-00)
- [Device Pairing Using Short Authentication Strings](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-kaiser-dnssd-pairing-00.html)